# basic server and client python

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted

I need to *stream* huge data from one machine to another, I need to do this using http,
`server` and `client`.
I have no idea on what `server` and `client` is as of now (network perse).

What **I am assuming** is
I have a server running on
IP `192.168.1.250`, Port `8080`
waiting to receive data and I have a client which sends data from another computer.
I have seen some frameworks, `Twisted` and Python's `BaseHTTPServer` modules.

`Twisted` has some good documentation, but I am unclear of what is being explained first...

I think **my requirement** is very basic.
Where to start, so at least what I can do is just send a file from my client and receive on the server side.
I am not using browser type programming. It's complete application.
I get the details from a named pipe.

My data maybe in few 10's GBs or may even extend to more than 100GB.
What I am trying to achieve is replication of certain files.

**My question is**
Where do I start with server and client design? Something, I have no idea how to do.

Comment: How much is "huge" data, and why do you [think you] need to use http for this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my manager tells me he wants to use 8080 port and with http it is more secured.

Comment: http is not secured, maybe you meant https on port 443.  regardless, neither is particularly appropriate protocol for _streaming huge data_

Comment: You will not want to use http for transferring huge files. Why don't you use FTP? [This](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) is a library I used for some projects, and it works nicely.

Comment: Thanks i will look into ftp transfer.

Comment: http is just as well-suited to file transfer as ftp.  Despite what people say about "FTP" having been "designed for file transfer", it wasn't designed very well.  It is overly complex, poorly specified, and doesn't actually work better than HTTP in practice.  Don't waste your time with that.  The result will not be any better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python i assume you have some access to a cli, so my first advice should be to stop the use of custom programming and use FTP protocol, because it has been designed for file transfer... Have a look [nearby](https://superuser.com/questions/142324/easy-to-setup-ftp-server-on-linux)

Comment: i will take a look at ftp transfers